# Swift, слайдер с порогами (логарифмическая линейка)

Tags: ios, swift, slider

Всем привет. Есть такая библиотека - TTRangeSlider. Требуется на его основе сделать а-ля логарифмический сладер.

[0, 50, 100, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 7500, 10000, 15000 ...]

Здесь можно взглянуть, примерно как оно должно работать.
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multistepslider

Уже давно бы закончил с библиотекой, но в TTRangeSlider нет возможности отследить нынешнее положение точек относительно 0% и 100%, т.е. value что ли. Ну и не получилось достучаться до лэйблов.

Что порекомендуете? Как решить ситуацию без замены библиотеки?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!
Можно управлять лэйблами в функции делегата TTRangeSliderDelegate:

```
 func rangeSlider(_ sender: TTRangeSlider!, didChangeSelectedMinimumValue selectedMinimum: Float, andMaximumValue selectedMaximum: Float) {
    print("min: \(selectedMinimum) max: \(selectedMaximum)")
     minLabel.text = convertToLabel(selectedMinimum)
    maxLabel.text = convertToLabel(selectedMaximum)

}
```

Но, наверное, так некрасиво. Лучше сделать кастомизированный UIControl из TTRangeSlider и 2 UILabel.

Хорошо описано, как  это можно сделать тут:
http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

Пример (и просто с управлением через функцию делегата, и с добавлением кастомизированного слайдера на основе TTRangeSlider) тут:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Dvz4/sfsLmyD8x

Управление положением слайдера идет через свойства selectedMaximum/selectedMinimun. Их преобразование в значение массива выполняет функция convertToLabel().

```
func convertToLabel(_ value:Float)-> String {
    let scale = Float((ttSlider.maxValue - ttSlider.minValue)/Float(logArray.count - 1))
    let scaledPosition = value - ttSlider.minValue
    let nodeNumber = Int(floor(scaledPosition/scale))
    guard nodeNumber < logArray.count && nodeNumber >= 0
        else {
            return "N/A"
    }
    return "\(logArray[nodeNumber])"
}
```

Comment: Кайф, спасибо, буду проверять!)))

Comment: Проверил, все окей. Но я хотел немного иную реализацию: Изменять лейблы, привязанные к точкам, которые мы тягаем влево/вправо. Опыта не хватило, чтобы сделать через override =(